# file_get_contents() failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I am writing some php script to update the code on my sites. In order to do that I have written the following lines which checks for the update version and bring the name from where I use to distribute my updates ans then creates the link of that name. I have done something like this.

```
$filename = "http://www.hf-live.com/codeupdate/Get_Files_Name.php";
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
echo $contents;
```

I am getting this error

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Even though the file is present still I am getting the same error. I have turned on my `allow_url_fopen` to `on`. The above code is working from my local host but not from the server. I have to update a major bug fix and I am stuck.. Please someone help me soon..

Comment: It works fine in my computer. Is it possible that you've been banned? What do you get when you open it in your browser? What does `var_dump($http_response_header);` print?

Comment: @Alvaro : var_dump($http_response_header); It returns NULL

Comment: Is that the exact code you are using? That works ok, http://codepad.viper-7.com/eP3K6G

Comment: Yes I am using the same code.. That means, I have some server settings disabled. Or there may be some additional security features added by the server. Can you point out some of them enabling which I could make file_get_contents() work.. ??

Comment: In the comments to answer below you say that "$filename = "hf-live.com/codeupdate/Get_Files_Name.php";" is the content of your $filename variable. So, what is the exact code that you are using?

Comment: I am only using these three lines to check for the names of the update I have set
$filename = "http://www.hf-live.com/codeupdate/Get_Files_Name.php";
 $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
 echo $contents;
which returns me the name of the latest zip set as update which later on is taken through get files content and extracted to my root folder.. I am in strong doubt that some of the setting is turned off ..

Comment: If your $filename does not start with http:// or https:// it will not fetch data over internet. So, just start using the code that you wrote in the actual question and it will work.

Comment: Now I am getting "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"...

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove extra .php from url

```
   $filename = "http://www.hf-live.com/codeupdate/Get_Files_Name.php";
```

You will get error if you are doing this way...

```
   $filename = "marynyhof.com/Info.php"; // will give you error, which exactly you are getting
```

use full url like this

```
   $filename = "http://www.marynyhof.com/Info.php"; //will work
```

Comment: @Yunus for your kind info your script is working fine.. it' showing some .zip file is there

Comment: You are trying from your localhost ??

Comment: Its working from my local too.. but that is not working from server... try this link "http://marynyhof.com/CustomCheck.php" here you will see the error.. And it has the same code as I have posted above...

Comment: @Yunus - Is that your live page? That `file_get_contents()` is not loading a HTTP document, it's loading a local file!

Comment: Yes I am sure.. I have been trying that since morning.. and here is the link if you wanna see the info http://marynyhof.com/Info.php .. What do you think I am missing in the code..

Comment: IF it works on one machine and not another, then I'm guessing one machine has allow_url_fopen set to 0. http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: When I use http:// then some other weird problem occurs.. The page keeps on loading until time out. I have added http://, so that you can run that page and see...Connection timed out .. Just copy the path inside the function and run it, it will work and show that the php exists..

Comment: I have a site hf-live.com which I use to set the update and distribute to all the other sites. So I have used $filename = "http://www.hf-live.com/codeupdate/Get_Files_Name.php"; which looks for the current update set from all the other sites. In the line above when I use http:// and then from other site if I check for updates, then the page keeps on loading until timeout. So I m trying to check update from marynyhof.com which will look at hf-live.com for any updates and provide it..

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507