# Error failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file_get_contents()

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to show content of text file (1.txt) by using file_get_contents() function, and of course I'm working with yii2 framework.

if there is simpler function in yii2 please suggest me.

Here is my code in controller:

```
public function actionRandom() {

        $fileContent = file_get_contents(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/files/upload/1.txt',true);
        echo Json::encode($fileContent);
        Yii::app()->end();

        return $this->render('random', [
                        ]
        );
    }
```

I get this error in result.

```
file_get_contents(/test/files/upload/1.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The file is exist in the path, but I don't know why I get this error.

These answers didn't help me well.

[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349562/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562368/file-get-contents-how-to-fix-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file)

Comment: add http:// to the start of the file_get_contents part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an absolute url

```
use yii\helpers\Url

Url::to(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl  .'/files/upload/1.txt' , true);
$fileContent = file_get_contents(Url::to(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl  
         .'/files/upload/1.txt' , true),true);
```

Comment: I want to have the content of file in a variable. not link to that.

Comment: The answer shoul provide the correct link for file_get_contents() then file_get:contents should return the content of the file in $fileContent

Answer (score 0):

if u sure file Url or path is correct, so check file permissions.

Comment: how do I have to do that?

Comment: sudo chmod 775 filename

Comment: I couldn't understand. please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents(dirname(__DIR__).'/../web/files/upload/1.txt',true);
```

will works if your file exists '/yourproject/web/files/upload/1.txt'